# JSTree: get attribute of a node

Tags: attributes, jstree

I use JSTree to display a tree with this syntax:

```
<ul>
    <li>Node 1
       <ul>
          <li url="anUrl.html">child node 1</li>
          <li url="anSecondUrl.html">child node 2</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to find the corresponding url when we select the child node 1?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You must use the activate_node.jstree event.  It passes in a data object which includes the node.  You take the ID from the node and look it up in the DOM and then you can access the attributes associated.  My example is probably a little different than what you are doing since I initialize the tree with a hierarchical JSON data object.

```
var treeMain;

$(document).ready(function ()
{

    treeMain = $('#treeMenus').jstree({
        core: {                                // this is just my optional configuration stuff for the tree
            data: sData,                       // I pass in a hierarchical JSON datasource calls sData
            multiple: false,
            error: function (evt, data) {
                alert(evt);
            },
            check_callback: null,              // had to include this to get the builtin popup menu to work
        }, 
        themes: { stripes: true },
        plugins: ["contextmenu", "dnd", "search", "state", "types", "wholerow"]

    });

    treeMain.on("activate_node.jstree", function (evt, data) {
        var oElement = $("#" + data.node.id)[0];
        var sURL = oElement.attributes["class"].value;  // you would use URL here, I used class in my test since I knew it would have that attribute
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice ! Works fine for me after long time to search.

I was looking for how Hide or Show Divs according to the node type (category or product). I add type attribute in li :  or

Here's my code :

```
$(function () {

    $('#jstree').jstree();

    // To show or hide a specific DIV according to the type value
    $('#jstree').on('changed.jstree', function (e, data) {
        var oElement = $("#" + data.node.id)[0];
        var type = oElement.attributes["type"].value;   
        if (type == 'prod') {
            show_prod();
        } else {
            hide_prod();   
        }
    }); 
});
```